# How to run notify.js in Laravel 4 when validation returns errors?

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, notify

I want to use the notify.js in Laravel whenever a controller's method returns validations errors.

By now I am using the normal bootstrap's alerts:

In the controller:

```
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput()
        ->with('global','<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="institucion_edited" align="center">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        Se han encontrado errores. Favor de verificar.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                        </div>
                        ');
```

The Javascript of the view:

```
<script>
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".alert-message,.alert-danger").fadeTo(2858, 0).slideUp(600, function(){
                $(this).remove(); 
            });
        }, 3000);
</script>
```

I have read the docs of notify.js and i see that it activates by itself, then how can i use the notify.js alert just when i return the validation errors list? I have thought of using the element selector:

```
<script>
        $(".alert-danger").notify({
            title: '<strong>Heads up!</strong>',
            message: 'You can use any of bootstraps other alert styles as well by default.'
        },{
            type: 'danger'
        });
</script>
```

But this does not work.
How can I fix it? Any ideas?